# How can I change the tag given when using git describe?

Tags: git, tags

I want to use "git describe" to get the "revision number" of the application.
Unfortunately, the git repository was created using cvs-import and has an ugly old tag, so I would like to change it.

How can I change the tag given when using "git describe"?

Note: I asked this on IRC today and found the answer myself in the end. Thought it might be useful to others too. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#create a new anotated tag because by default git describes only looks for those
git tag -a NEWTAG

#push the new tags to the remote repository
git push --tags
```

cf: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html

This may also be of interest to you:
[How can I pass the output of a command as a compiler flag through a Qt project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852437/how-can-i-pass-the-output-of-a-command-as-a-compiler-flag-through-a-qt-project-fi)

Comment: http://www.rockstarprogrammer.org/post/2008/oct/16/git-tag-does-wrong-thing-default/

Comment: Thanks for the info. So signed tags can be used too. :)

Answer (score 0):

git describe now supports a --match option that can filter the tags that will be selected